# Why do I get: Syntax error unexpected 'endwhile'?

Tags: php, mysqli, syntax-error

Here is my code:

index.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once "db_connect.php";

$sql = "SELECT forum_id, forum_name FROM froum_table";

if($query = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($f_id, $f_name);
    $query->store_result();
} else {
    echo $db->error;
}

?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta charest="utf-8">
    <title>my2</title>
   </head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <table align="center" width="80%">
            <?php
            if($query->num_rows !== 0):
            while($row = $query->fetch()):
            ?>
            <tr>
               <td><a href="froum.php?id=<?php echo $f_id; ?>"><?php echo                $f_name; ?></a></td>
            </tr>
             <?php endwhile; endif;?>
        </table>
     </div>       
  </body>
  </html>
```

db_connect.php:

```
<?php

    $db = new mysqli ("localhost","root".""."fourm") or die ("ERROR! withe connection");

?>
```

I'm getting these errors:

> No database selected
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\my2\index.php on line 29
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\my2\index.php on line 30

here code my database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_tabl` (
`forum_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`forum_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`forum_description` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `forum_tabl`
--

INSERT INTO `forum_tabl` (`forum_id`, `forum_name`, `forum_description`)    VALUES
 (1, 'web design', 'a forum about web design');

 --
 -- Indexes for dumped tables
 --

 --
 -- Indexes for table `forum_tabl`
 --
 ALTER TABLE `forum_tabl`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`forum_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `forum_tabl`
--
ALTER TABLE `forum_tabl`
MODIFY `forum_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: You misspelled `forum_tabl`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not just that. Look at it again ;-) `SELECT froum_id, forum_name FORM froum_tabl`

Comment: @JayBlanchard `SELECT column FORUM that TABLE` might even work better. *Not*

Comment: heh ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ @Fred-ii- My cold addled brain can just barely discern one problem at a time.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Don't you like it when something riddled as such, adds to the riddle? I'm not talking Batman & The Riddler, but he was a gas!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I haven't seen that many typos since I last held a take-out menu from a "certain restaurant that will remain nameless". Rizier123's picking up on those; I'm sure he must also grow "cactus"; a patient patient man he is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This answer is from the first revision:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28546869/1

You have a few things wrong in your code.

1.  Wrong alternative syntax

```
if($query->num_rows !==0);
                       //^
//...
while($row = $query->fetch());
                           //^ Currently your loop executes this empty statement
```

Just change the semicolons to commas like this:

```
while($row = $query->fetch()):
                           //^ See here alternative syntax
//...
if($query->num_rows !==0):
                       //^
```

For more information about alternative syntax see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

2. Misspelling

You misspelled `FORM` in your SQL query wrong, just change it to: `FROM`

Also i think `froum_id` should be: `forum_id`

And in your html:

```
<td><a herf ...
     //^^^^ Should be 'href'
```

And from the comment from @Jay Blanchard:

> You misspelled forum_tabl

I think you want to write: `forum_table`

3. Wrong `bind_result()` call

```
$query->bind_result($f_id. $f_name);
                       //^ Replace '.' with ','
```

4. Wrong order

```
$query->bind_result($f_id, $f_name);
      //^^^^^^^^^^^ This comes after the execution
$query->execute;
            //^ Missing '()'
```

5. Missing quotes

Here you forgot a double quote:

```
<table align="center" width=80%">
```

should be:

```
<table align="center" width="80%">
                          //^
```

6. Wrong connection call

From the comments as far as i can tell you are mixing commas with dots:

```
<?php $db = new mysqli ("localhost","root".""."fourm") or die ("ERROR! withe connection"); ?>
                                        //^  ^ Should be commas
```

So use something like this:

```
<?php

    $db = new mysqli ("localhost", "root","", "fourm");

    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $db->connect_errno . ') '
                . $db->connect_error);
    }

?>
```

(And as always i have the suspicion that you want to write: `forum` and not `fourm`)

So at the end your code should look something like this:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once "db_connect.php";
    
    $sql = "SELECT forum_id, forum_name FROM froum_table";
    
    if($query = $db->prepare($sql)) {
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($f_id, $f_name);
    } else {
        echo $db->error;
    }
    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charest="utf-8">
        <title>my2</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <table align="center" width="80%">
                <?php
                if($query->num_rows !== 0):
                while($row = $query->fetch()):
                ?>
                <tr>
                   <td><a href="froum.php?id=<?php echo $f_id; ?>"><?php echo $f_name; ?></a></td>
                </tr>
                 <?php endwhile; endif;?>
            </table>
        </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i add everything info want to help thanks you

Comment: @ALANZEI Saw my update(Point 6)? Does it works now for you? Since you accepted it?

Comment: now erro Table 'fourm.froum_table' doesn't exist

Comment: @ALANZEI Are you sure you didn't wanted to write: `forum_table` ? Also did you copied both of my codes for `index.php` and `db_connect.php`?

Comment: u can see all my code in my Question

and in database name= forum_tabl

Comment: @ALANZEI Okay, then take a look again at Point 6 in my answer. You almost corrected everything :D (Also make sure your table names are correct: `froum_table` and `fourm`)

Comment: i change it and show 

     Table 'fourm.forum_table' doesn't exist

Comment: @ALANZEI Then it's only a thing that you use a wrong table name. Just check the name in your database

Comment: i check database and add code database in Question

Comment: @ALANZEI yep saw it. Then also just make sure in your connection the name is right and change your sql query with this table name: `forum_tabl`

Comment: yes thnx man for help thx dude

Comment: @ALANZEI You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: If want to know how to do something on SO see the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: okay thnx for info man